# XML content assist is not working even if included DTD

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, struts2, xml-configuration

In Eclipse `struts.xml` content assist is not working with even included DTD in XML. but seems like am missing something here. I have all required jars in lib and build path as well.

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
.....
```

Comment: Are you using free or commercial version of Eclipse?

Comment: am using free version of eclipse.

Comment: you should register the dtd with eclipse, so it knows the document and include it in validation.

Comment: can u pls guide me, how to register the dtd with eclipse

Comment: Which Eclipse are you using? Do you have internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML file associations with DTD.

When an XML file is associated with a DTD, it is bound by any structural rules contained in the DTD. To be considered a valid XML file, a document must be accompanied by a DTD, and conform to all of the declarations in the DTD.

You can use XML schema instead of DTD to make an association with XML document but no XML schema provided.

> There are two different ways to associate XML files with DTDs or XML
>   schemas.
>
> - Direct association - The XML file contains either the name of a
>     DTD in its doctype declaration (for example, , where dtdfile.dtd is the name of the DTD file)
>     or it contains the path of an XML schema in the schemaLocation
>     attribute of the XML file root element (for example,
>     , where schema.xsd
>     is the name of the XML schema.
> - XML Catalog entry - You can
>     register DTD and XML schema files in the XML Catalog and associate
>     them with a Key that represents them. You can then refer to a DTD or
>     XML schema file Key from an XML file instead of referring directly to
>     the DTD or XML schema file. An XML Catalog entry contains two parts -
>     the Key (which represents the DTD or XML schema) and a URI (which
>     contains information about the DTD or XML schema location).

---

## Editing the XML Catalog Settings

The XML Catalog can be accessed via the Eclipse preferences:

1. Select **Window** -> **Preferences** to launch the Preferences dialog.
2. In the navigation tree expand the **Web and XML** group and select **XML Catalog**.

The picture below shows how to change settings

[image]

---

**References:**

- [XML file associations with DTDs and XML schemas](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user/topics/cxmlcat.html?cp=66_2_2_3)
- [Using the XML Catalog](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_the_XML_Catalog)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my content assist dtd issue,

> I have extracted struts-2.0-dtd from struts2-core-2.0.1.jar and
>   created a folder as dtds in WEB-INF and placed above extracted dtd in
>   dtds folder.In struts.xml i changed dtd location as

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN"
    "/WEB-INF/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
```

It is working now.. am able to see the content assist for my struts.xml